# Library for handling a List of Ranges

Tags: java, numbers, range, guava, date-range

I have to handle a list of timestamps (`Long`) in a Java 8 application:

If a user adds a new range, it should be merged together with the other existing ranges, like in this pseudo code:

```
rangeList = [100, 200], [300, 400], [500, 600], [700, 800]
newRangeList = rangeList.add([150, 550])
println(newRangeList)      // Expected output: [100, 600], [700, 800]
```

I tried using a `List` of [Google Guava Range class](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/RangesExplained) but merging together new timestamp ranges gets surprisingly complicated.

Using the new [LongStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/LongStream.html) from Java 8 instead of the Range class doesn't helped me.

I think an [Interval Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) would be a good data structure to handle merging efficient, but I found no library which is implementing this.

Is there a library for handling numeric ranges and merging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what you want to achieve, and since you mention using Guava's Range, Guava already has what you want: a [`RangeSet`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/RangeSet.html).

The javadoc for this interface specifies that:

> [...]Implementations that choose to support the add(Range) operation are required to ignore empty ranges and **coalesce connected ranges**.

It is an interface; you probably want to use a [`TreeRangeSet`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeRangeSet.html) for your purposes:

```
// for whatever type C...
final RangeSet<C> rangeSet = TreeRangeSet.create();
```