# Need kind of 'interval ranges' computations

Tags: c++, types, complex-data-types

I need a library for my C++ program.
But the problem, I don't know the name of this data type I want.

I have NPAPI plugin (I know this API is deprecated and removed from modern browsers) which issues to a server 
HTTP range requests. Request is asyncronious and the data may arraive in any order with any chunks size.

So I need to track ranges I already have requested from a server.

For example, if initially I requested bytes [10-20] (inclusevely), then I requested [30-40] the data type I need should keep it as two intervals:

```
[10-20],[30-40]
```

But if I request [21-29] or even [15-35] it should be merged in one interval:

```
[10-20],[30-40] + [15-35] = [10-40]
```

Also I need a substraction when a requested block arrives:

```
[10-40] - [20-30] = [10-19],[31-40]
```

(requested - arrived = we're still waiting for)

I had a look at **boost::numeric::intervals** library but at first glance it is too big for this task (1583 files, 13 Mb of sources after './dist/bin/bcp numeric/interval ~/boost').

Also, **GNU ddrescue** has some similar arithmetics inside but the code isn't a library there, it coupled too much with the applications specifics.

UPDATE:

Here is what I've found on my way:

[A container for integer intervals, such as RangeSet, for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32869247/a-container-for-integer-intervals-such-as-rangeset-for-c)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree

Boost.ICL

NCBI C++ Toolkit, CIntervalTree

Comment: What is the largest value that you need to handle (x-y)?

Comment: It should be enough to handle a several Gb file.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merging-intervals/

Comment: drescherjm, yes, but there only merge. And this is a code snippet, not a library. But thanks anyway, this is the right direction for me.

Comment: Looks like [Boost ICL interval_container](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/icl/doc/html/boost_icl/examples/interval_container.html) is something you looking for.